# How To Add Subtitle to VLC Activex Tool In VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, video, vlc, subtitle

Hello guys i have a problem on my project. I have a online video and one subtitle in my directory so i want to play video with subtitle on vlc activex tool. i tried this code but it doesnt work for me.

```
     AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("http://*****/video.mkv", "Title", ":sub-file=file:///C:\Users\Asım\\b****\1x1.srt")
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
```

the video is playing but the subtitle is not showing. how can i fix it? (also i tried it :   AxVLCPlugin21.video.subtitle = 1)

Comment: hello guys any help?

Comment: axvlcplugin is not supported, I highly encourage you to use Vlc.DotNet or LibVLCSharp